# How to listen to changes in spring batch job status without polling batch job execution table at a certain time interval?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

As we know that spring batch job goes through below statuses during its run, I want to listen to these status changes in real time and make a post call to the rest api with the current status.

For Ex: 
1.When a job "X" has launched, its initial status is "STARTING", i want to listen to this status change and make a call to rest api
2.When a job "X" status has changed to "STARTED', then i want to listen to this status change and make a call to rest api
...

You get the point, right?

### DIFFERENT STATUSES OF SPRING BATCH JOB

- ABANDONED
- COMPLETED
- FAILED
- STARTED
- STARTING
- STOPPED
- STOPPING
- UNKNOWN

I know that job repository is responsible for making CRUD operations on the batch_job_execution table, but how can i listen to those changes from the java code?

Answer (score 1):

> how can i listen to those changes from the java code?

This is possible but not for all status changes. The [`JobExecutionListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecutionListener.html) allows you to get notified when:

- the job starts (status `STARTING` -> `STARTED`)
- and when it finishes (status `STARTED` -> [`STOPPED` | `COMPLETED` | `FAILED`].

Hope this helps.